# NPM: Can't require globally installed module

Tags: node.js, npm

I am trying to require the NPM package `browserify`, which I have installed globally through this command:

```
npm install -g browserify
```

This is the file `bundle.js` in which I try to require browserify:

```
var browserify = require('browserify');
var fs = require('fs');
var b = browserify();

var outputFileStream = fs.createWriteStream('./test_bundle.js');

b.add('index.js');
b.bundle().pipe(outputFileStream);  // process.stdout
```

When I do `node build.js` I get this error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'browserify'
( etcetera...)
```

If I then instead install browserify locally:

```
npm install -g browserify
```

I get no error and the build goes just fine.

I have uploaded a small demo program to this Github repository:

https://github.com/loldrup/test_require

So if you're on a Windows 7 machine, you should be able to reproduce my error simply by cloning:

```
git clone https://github.com/loldrup/test_require
```

and running:

```
node build
```

**EDIT:**

even after adding relevant node paths to my system variable 'path', and restarted the command promt, I still can't require globally installed node modules:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Node.js doesn't look in the folder where global modules are installed by default.

Add **module.paths.push('*path to global node_modules*')** at the beginning of the script or [set up the enviroment variables](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_the_global_folders).

Comment: Even with my `PATH` now looking like this:
`%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;...etc...;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\Jon\AppData\Roaming\npm\``
I get an error: `module.js:328`, `throw err;`, `Error: Cannot find module 'browserify'

Comment: You forgot to add node_modules: C:\Users\Jon\AppData\npm\node_modules

Comment: still no luck. see updated text/image in the question.

Comment: For me on Ubuntu it worked with `module.paths.push("/usr/local/lib/node_modules");` added to the begning of `webpack.config.js`. Thanks!